# How do I prohibit dragging of imdistline vertices?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing

I try to draw a distance measurement line tool: `h = imdistline(handles.image)` and after I set the initial measurement I want to prohibit the user from adjusting it again. So what I want is to set the ending vertices not draggable.

So far this is what I came up with:

```
h = imdistline(handles.image);
wait(h) % waiting for user interaction
initial_pos = h.getPosition();
fcn = makeConstrainToRectFcn('imline', initial_pos(:,1)',initial_pos(:,2)');
setPositionConstraintFcn(h, fcn);
```

That still lets me drag the vertices along the specified line. How do I specify a position constraint function that does not let me drag the vertices any more? I'd appreciate alternate routes as well.

I use MATLAB 2018b.